# JAVA: Parentheses match method not printing

Tags: java, algorithm, search

Hey I am doing a programming assignment and we have to match parentheses in a String. We have to output an Error message such as the following:

*Sample I/O:*

Enter a string to test:
( < [ { } ( { > ) ] >

**error: '>' does not match with '{'.**

I am trying to print this message in my isBalanced() method however it will not print the System.out.println() however it is reaching that code block (otherwise it would never return false) which it is. I think the problem lies in my main method but I have been trying for a while now and I am stumped! 
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks,

Kyle.

```
  import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.Stack; //using java's default stack in this case as it has more extraneous error checking
public class Question3 {
    private static final String OPEN = "([{<";
    private static final String CLOSED = ")]}>";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader inKb = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));

        System.out.println("Enter a test string:");
        String input = inKb.readLine();

        boolean successful = isBalanced(input);
        System.out.println(successful);
    }

    public static void printError(char ch, char expected) {
        System.out.println("Error: '" + ch + "' does not match with '"
                + expected + "'");
    }

    private static boolean isOpen(char bracket) {
        return OPEN.indexOf(bracket) >= 0;
    }

    private static boolean isClosed(char bracket) {
        return CLOSED.indexOf(bracket) >= 0;
    }

    private static boolean matches(char openBracket, char closedBracket) {
        return OPEN.indexOf(openBracket) == CLOSED.indexOf(closedBracket);
    }

    public static boolean isBalanced(String input) {
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                char ch = input.charAt(i);
                if (isOpen(ch)) {
                    stack.push(ch);
                } else if (isClosed(ch)) {
                    char corBracket = stack.pop(); // pop corresponding bracket
                    if (!matches(ch, corBracket)) {
                        System.out.println("Print Test!"); //Not printing?
                        return false;
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (EmptyStackException ex) {
            return false;
        }

        return stack.isEmpty(); //if stack is empty then the corresponding bracket wasn't found!
    }
}
```

Comment: There IS another way it can return false:  If EmptyStackException is caught or if the end of the method is reached and stack.isEmpty() is false.  Try using print statements to see if either of these are happening.

Comment: Add a sysout in the catch EmptyStackException so you can make sure it is the exception the one returning false.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
if (!matches(ch, corBracket)) {
```

`ch` is the closing and `corBracket` is the opening. You need to reverse them

```
if (!matches(corBracket, ch)) {
```

to match the method semantics

```
private static boolean matches(char openBracket, char closedBracket) {
    boolean value = OPEN.indexOf(openBracket) == CLOSED.indexOf(closedBracket);
    return value;
}
```

You use descriptive names in the `matches` method. You should do the same everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example where it would be useful to use a debugger.

Debugging your application with the input `( < )` tells me that `!matches(ch, corBracket)` is evaluated as `false` and therefore your if statement is ignored. This leads us to believe that your `matches(char, char)` method is incorrect.

If you try changing your `matches` method to the following:

```
private static boolean matches(char openBracket, char closedBracket) {
  int i1 = OPEN.indexOf(openBracket);
  int i2 = CLOSED.indexOf(closedBracket);

  return (i1 == i2);
}
```

You will see in your debugger that `i1` and `i2` are both `-1` (the return value of `indexOf` in the case of no occurrence) and since `-1 == -1` evaluates to true, `!(-1 == -1)` evaluates to `false`, as expected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks all! I just realised that they hinted that I use two stacks. So let's say I had a stack called stack and a temp stack. If the parentheses is an opening parentheses. We push it onto the stack. If the parentheses is a closing brace, we firstly pop it off stack and then push it onto the temp stack and pop it off until a opposite parentheses is found. Any help on the algorithm for this? Unsure exactly how to go about this...

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for opening brakets in `CLOSED` and for closing brackets in `OPENED`!

you need to change

```
 return OPEN.indexOf(openBracket) == CLOSED.indexOf(closedBracket);
```

into

```
 return CLOSED.indexOf(openBracket) == OPEN.indexOf(closedBracket);
```

or just swap the parameters in your call

```
matches(corBracket, ch)
```

instead of

```
matches(ch, corBracket)
```

debuging into the call that function would have show you that `OPEN.indexOf(openBracket)` return `-1` witch is supicious since you are expecting to find what you are searching for i.e. an index which is greater or equal than 0 and less than OPEN.length()